# Assistance w/ Export-Csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-csv

I am using the script below to reference a txt file with a list of computer names to find out what OS and OS version each machine is on. I can get it to display in PowerShell but all the attempts I've made to have it export to a CSV file have failed. I have used other articles on here that recommend using Write-output and Export-csv but all I get is either and error (depending on placement) or I get a CSV file that shows length and the character count. I don't mind putting in the work but I feel like I am not understanding where I would place a pipe and have the results go to a CSV file.

```
$Computers = Import-Csv -Path "c:\Scripts\computers.txt" -Header "Name"
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    try {
        Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer.Name -Properties Name, operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion |
            Select Name, operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion
    } catch {
        $Computer.Name + " not in AD" |
            Export-Csv -Path .\computers-results.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Computers = Import-CSV -Path "c:\Scripts\computers.txt" -Header "Name"

$Result = ForEach ($Computer In $Computers)
{
  Try
  {
      Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer.Name -Properties Name, operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion | Select Name, operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion
  }
  Catch
  {
      Write-Warning $Computer.Name + " not in AD"
  }
}

$Result | Export-CSV .\computers-results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This works by collating the result of the `ForEach` loop in to the `$Result` variable, which happens because the result of the `Get-ADComputer` line is being returned to the pipeline.

Once the loops is complete `$Result` is a collection of objects that we can then sent to `Export-CSV` to convert to a CSV file.

Note i've also changed the `Catch` part to use `Write-Warning` so you'll only see in your console the machines that can't be reached, they won't appear in your output file at all.

Comment: Mark, that was it. Thank you for taking the time to break down the explanation. I am definitely adding everything you stated to my notes so I can get better at doing my due diligence. That was simplified response and completely makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: You’re very welcome!